# Creating a simple Safari extension

Tags: safari

I have been trying to make a simple Safari extension, but I can't find any documentation online and am a little overwhelmed. I want to create an extension for my own personal use, which injects a small line of Javascript to each page (specifically, I want it to redirect certain URLs, say changing "yahoo.com" to "google.com", but I'm not sure that matters so much).

How do I do this?

I have x-code, and I've tried making a bunch of different Safari extension projects and asking chatGPT for help, but I can't produce anything that injects custom JS. I get a little overwhelmed by all the default files in a Safari web extension default project -- I don't really know what does what, and explanations I find online are usually too old to be relevant.